# How to access iframe internal url when user goes to next page in iframe only (inside iframe)

Tags: html

how to retrieve the url from an iframe, when a user goes or clicks to next page inside iframe.
**i mean for website which allows x-frame-options.**

(src attribute is on external server page)

Eg:`<iframe src="http://www.google.com"></iframe>`
An user types a word in google's search engine and clicks on  search button (inside iframe) the iframe renders a new page about the search page and again the user clicks on some link inside it, iframe renders a new page ,I want to retrieve the url for which the user click on it inside the iframe.

Comment: try `document.getElementById("iframe_id").contentWindow.location.href`

Comment: i did try that code,but it shows same "src" URL

Comment: `<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<button onclick="s()">Click me</button>
<iframe id="frame" src="http://www.v--------------.com">
  <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
</iframe>
<div id="n"></div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function s(){
  var a=document.getElementById("frame").contentWindow.location.href;

$("#n").text(a);
}

</script>


</body>
</html>`

Comment: its showing blank

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do this would be via Javascript. If you give the iframe an id, such as `iframeId`, you can do something like:

```
document.getElementById("iframeId").contentWindow.location.‌​href
```

Answer (score 0):

I googled on other website,but there is no solution for this,iframe tag is built to view contents of the page only,like frameset.

As developers we need to disable external clicking from the user inside the iframe content as it violates some hacking from other website content.